# use predict in points statement

Tags: regression, points, predict

I am new to R and am having trouble with predicting and plotting a testing dataset from training linear regression results.

I have a training dataset with 516 observations
 and a testing dataset with 10 observations

I ran a linear regression on the training data
  train2.lm=lm(CO2~Period+P2, data=training)
  summary(train2.lm)

Then I plotted my testing data and turned the color red
  plot(testing$CO2~testing$Period, col="red")

Now I want to put the estimated test points on the same plot as my actual testing data to see how well my model predicted actual data.

points(testing$Period,predict(train2.lm), col="orange")

I get the following error

Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

I think this has something to do with my training dataset having more values. I need to use the regression from training to predict and plot CO2 in my testing.

Comment: try predicting on the testing set instead of the training set

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, here is an example of what could alleviate the problem. Building a linear regression on the iris dataset...

```
# 150 samples in the iris dataset
n = nrow(iris)
train_ind = sample(n,size=50)
# training set is 50 random samples
train = iris[train_ind,]
# testing set is 100 random samples (i.e. n - 50)
test = iris[-train_ind,]

# build a silly model on the training set
train.lm = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width,data=train)
# predict on the training set
pred_train = predict(train.lm)
# 50 predictions
length(pred_train)

# use the fitted model to predict on the testing set
pred = predict(train.lm, newdata=list(Sepal.Width = test$Sepal.Width))
# 100 predictions
length(pred)
```